# Get data field of the selected row in Gridview using button field in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

There are two pages named: People.aspx and Profile.aspx.

People.aspx -> contains the name of all users

Profile.aspx -> contains the information of each user

In the first page, People.aspx, I have a Gridview named **peopleGridview** and when I am loading the page name **People.aspx**, in `Page_Load` event I call a method that executes a sql query on database and gets all the fields that I need to put in my Gridview.

The SQL query is like this:

```
public DataSet PeopleList()
    {
        GetConnection();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Members.ID, Members.Full_Name, Members.Position, Members.Status, Profile.Address" +
                                            " FROM Members" +
                                            " INNER JOIN Profile" +
                                            " ON Members.ID = Profile.ID"+
                                            " ORDER BY Members.Priority, Members.Membership_Date, Members.Full_Name", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);//da: DataAdapter 
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();//ds: Dataset
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

In Gridview I only need to show the fields **Full_Name**, **Position**, **Status** and **Address** and I do not want to show the value of the field **ID** (because it is not necessary for ordinary users to know the ID of other users).

I have a button field in my Gridview for each row and I want whenever that I clicked on the button field of the selected row, read the field **ID** of the selected row (that is not currently shown in Gridview) and put it in the `Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx?UserID=" + userid.Text.ToString());` as an argument for the **userid** in order to send it to **Profile.aspx** that is another page that contains the information about that user.

How do I do such a work? In addition, how can I get the value of UserID on the side of Profile.aspx

I did the work using Link field in Gridview, however I am not able to do such a work using button field in GridView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get specific columns in grid view first set false value to Auto Generate Column `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` than bind your required field inside the Gridview Column.

html GridView :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Full_Name"  HeaderText="Full Name" SortExpression="Full Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Postion" SortExpression="Position" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address"  HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Profile">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnViewInq" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Viewmail.png" 
                        CommandName="ViewProfile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' ToolTip="View Profile" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# Code behind :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ViewProfile")
    {
        // id with get the Userid parameter that we set inside the button CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Send this value of id to your querystring to redirect to another page
        Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx?UserId=" + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is still a problem. I am a little confused. Where is the 'ID' field of my sql query? where did you get the value of 'ID' field of the selected row in your code?

Comment: read the comment in my code carefully. it says "CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'"  in your grid view button.

Comment: the CommandArgument should be 'ID' and not 'UserId' I think. because with your code I had an error and after changing the argument value to 'ID' I have no longer the error. But there is still another problem. when I click the button, the new page does not load and I get the error "Invalid postback or callback argument." What is this for?

Comment: dude, you need to change the code as per your need, we can give you logic. We don't know what fields you are using as we don't have a grip of your code. Last of all the things. People in here will help you with logic not Write the code for you.

Comment: I do know and I really appreciate your help. I am not an amateur programmer and I understand the logic. I should understand my self that I must change the name of UserId to ID, it is OK. I have another question. I told you when I click the button on the side of the other page I have a problem. It seems that Profile.aspx can not get the value of the UserId in its own side and I get an error like "Invalid postback or callback argument."

Comment: please ask new question on SO with sufficient information, so that others can understand help.